# OpenGL : Line jittering with large scene and small values

Tags: opengl-es, camera, line, culling, frustum

I'm currently drawing a 3D solar system and I'm trying to draw the path of the orbits of the planets. The calculated data is correct in 3D space but when I go towards Pluto, the orbit line shakes all over the place until the camera has come to a complete stop. I don't think this is unique to this particular planet but given the distance the camera has to travel I think its more visible at this range.

I suspect its something to do with the frustum but I've been plugging values into each of the components and I can't seem to find a solution. To see anything I'm having to use very small numbers (E-5 magnitude) for the planet and nearby orbit points but then up to E+2 magnitude for the further regions (maybe I need to draw it twice with different frustums?)

Any help greatly appreciated...

Comment: Sounds like you are hitting the limit of float accuracy. Try using double.

Comment: @Banthar: Won't help since most/all OpenGL implementations are single-precision internally.

Comment: You might be hitting the limits of your depth buffer resolution: essentially your far distance (1E+2) divided by your near distance (1E-5) should be less than 2^(number of bits in your depth buffer). In this case you need about 24 bits to cover a range of 1E+7. My Mac is 16 bits.

Comment: We've tried using doubles for similar reasons but I don't think this resolved a similar issue. The depth buffer limitation is what I am repeatedly coming up with - how would I extend the depth buffer range? (I've just noticed I've tagged this wrong - I should have tagged opengles as I'm working on Android)

Comment: Just to throw it out there: would it make sense that one way to fix this is to move the camera only halfway and make the planet move the exact same distance but in the opposite direction i.e. towards the camera?

Comment: @Banthar: The way I solved this is to do client side vertex projection and then select all the vertices that are nearer to the camera than the depth buffer limits will allow. Draw everything that is inside the depth buffer using the normal 3D pipeline, all that geometry gets drawn correctly for depth. For everything else, closer than the near distance, create a 2D projection and draw points/edges. I have a client side routine that will clip edges to the view port, points are easy. If you need to draw quads and triangle you need to clip them and remember there is no depth buffering in 2D.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for answering but my solution to this was to draw it with the same matrices that were drawing the planet since it wasn't bouncing around as well. So the solution really is to code better really, sorry.